# Dynamic WCF service adress with shared contracts c#

Tags: c#, wcf, dynamic, service

How can i create wcf service at runtime, I've searched but every question and answer I found is how to consume dynamic WCF services. But I want to create new adresses on the host or change the adress/name of an existing service.

ex
If a have my wcf service at some adress `http://somewhare:5751/default.svc` and I like to dynamiclly create a new service on the same host with the same contract,bindings etc just another adress `http://somewhare:5751/defaultCopy.svc` and it's going to be persistent.

Is this possible or should I do some sort of redirect traffic to the default.svc ?

Edit:
Why I want this is just because of it will be more user friendly, the user will create his own database(SDF). I could send parameters along with the calls to the service that defines the correct database, but It would be alot nicer if a user can specify their own name of the service.

Comment: you are looking for self host wcf service. there is a command line that allow you to host a WCF knowing the svc location or even better the DLL in the bin. You can give different name so same one can run gazillion times under different name but there is no point on duplicating end point to the same lib.

Comment: I guess, your service `default.svc` can hold a list of child services, that services can be created the same way any other self-hosted service is created, but if you want the services to run on the same port, look around for port-sharing. I am not posting any link, because it is not known to me, how and where you are planning to host your `default.svc` service and where the child-services.

Comment: The application is IIS hosted, the port doesen't relly matther I just want to be able to create a user friendly customizable adress